# Grouped collection in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm experiment with creating grouped collection in Ruby on Rails. I've created one with "select_tag" helper. It looks like this:
In my controller i have variable which is a hash:

```
 @cities = {
  'USA'      => ['Washington', 'New York'],
  'Bulgaria' => ['Sofia', 'Svishtov']
}
```

And in my form:

```
 = select_tag :handover_location, grouped_options_for_select(@cities)
```

And this produces mi nice select with optgroups labels. How can I do the same but with simple_form?

Comment: Try `grouped_options_for_select(@cities.to_a)`

Comment: Thank's for help. I tried to do:
= f.input :handover_location,grouped_options_for_select(@cities.to_a)
but it gives me an error:
"undefined method `each_pair' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x007f88d4dd0f68>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `simple_form`, try:

```
f.input :handover_location, collection: @cities, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :last, group_label_method: :first
```

(Not tested)

Comment: Thx! Works like harm :)